# Как сделать шаблонный цикл?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Я очень часто вожусь с циклами и они почти одинаковые, думаю что можно упростить много кода если будет один шаблон.

```
// блоки могут быть разные но число заранее известно до компиляции
const int block_1 = 10,
          block_2 = 4,
          block_3 = 6,
          block_4 = 3;
```

В основном все циклы такие

цикл может быть такой

```
for (int i = 1; i < block_1 - 1; ++i) {

}
```

или такой

```
for (int i = 1; i < block_1 - 1; ++i) {
    for (int k = 1; k < block_2 - 1; ++k) {

    }
}
```

или такой

```
for (int i = 1; i < block_1 - 1; ++i) {
    for (int k = 1; k < block_2 - 1; ++k) {
        for (int j = 1; j < block_3 - 1; ++j) {
          // тут пишу код 

        }
    }
}
```

Количество циклов внутри цикла может быть много, а так они похоже

Я вот думаю что если не делать постоянно циклы а использовать шаблон,
будет ли это удобней или нет, но возможно не стоит и вы меня отговорите это делать.

В идеале я бы хотел вот такой шаблон

```
for_funk(block_1, block_2, block_3) {
   // тут пишу код который будет внутри трех циклов block_1, block_2, block_3
}
```

Возможно это поможет https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2374r4.html

Comment: От шаблона тольку немного, потому что синтаксис будет не менее громоздкий. С макросом это возможно (даже авто-выбор названий счетчиков, с нестандартными прагмами), но те, кому придется читать код после вас, будут вас люто ненавидеть.

Comment: Лучше сделайте себе тип `vec3` (или сколько вам нужно, может быть `vec<N>`), а потом `for (vec3 pos : range(vec3(block1, block2, block3)))` (где `range` придется написать самому).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Так я думаю сделать один раз шаблон и в него больше не смотреть, просто описать как он работает, зачем кому то в него лезть.

Будут пользоваться но не смотреть как он выглядит.
А так понятное дело что шаблон будет большой и довольно запутанный

Comment: Ок. Но все равно, ranged-for лучше всего. В решении через макрос есть только спортивный интерес. А чистый шаблон будет выглядеть так: `loop(block_1, block_2, block_3, [&](int i, int j, int k){ ... })` (имхо, не очень).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 
а такой не получиться разве? `for_funk(block_1, block_2, block_3) {}`

Comment: Только макросом.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну макросы это такое себе удовольствие, я их никогда не использовал)

Comment: Можно же поверх шаблона сделать еще шаблон, тогда возможно без макросов будет

Comment: Судя по тому, что вы думаете, что такой шаблон возможен, вы и шаблонами немного пользовались. Такой синтаксис совершенно точно невозможен без макросов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да я плохо разбираюсь в шаблонах

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Но раз вы пишите не возможно, значит так и есть, а если иcпользовать C++23 или какой то еще новое который не вышел, возможно boost

Comment: Мне понравилась как это реализовано

`for (auto&& [ea,eb,ec] : std::views::cartesian_product(a,b,c)) {}`

Comment: Да, с такой записью можно. C++23 в этом никак не помогает, разве что если в него подвезут этот `cartesian_product`, но его можно и самому написать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чисто из академического интереса попробовал подобную конструкцию реализовать, через рекурсию в принципе такое возможно, рабочий пример прикладываю (его точно можно упростить, делал на коленке).

```
template<typename Callback, int Index, int Head, int... Tail>
void F(int counters[], Callback cbk)
{
    for (counters[Index] = 0; counters[Index] < Head; ++counters[Index])
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Tail) > 0)
            F<Callback, Index + 1, Tail...>(counters, cbk);
        else
            cbk(counters);
    }
}

template<int... N>
void F(std::function<void(int counters[sizeof...(N)])> cbk)
{
    int counters[sizeof...(N)];
    F<std::function<void(int counters[sizeof...(N)])>, 0, N...>(counters, cbk);
}

int main()
{
    F<1, 2, 3>([](int counters[3]){ std::cout << counters[0] << " " << counters[1] << " " << counters[2] << std::endl; });
}
```

Comment: Хороший пример, жалко что с использованием рекурсии, они довольно медленные.